# Unable to do a git pull - related to upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04?

Tags: git

Everytime I execute git pull origin master on my laptop, I get an error.  This does not happen on any of my other computers or linux servers.  The only difference with my laptop is that I recently upgraded from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. Here are my terminal commands that generate the error:

```
www-data@john-laptop:~/huf$ git init
www-data@john-laptop:~/huf$ git remote add origin http://gitjohn@git.mywebsite.com/em-microsite
www-data@john-laptop:~/huf$ git pull origin master
Password for 'http://gitjohn@git.mywebsite.com': 
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 (curl_result = 22, http_code = 401, sha1 = 65a9a62cd53a7533ce48a463d5fa5622734bc38b)
error: Unable to find 65a9a62cd53a7533ce48a463d5fa5622734bc38b under http://gitjohn@git.mywebsite.com/em-microsite
Cannot obtain needed commit 65a9a62cd53a7533ce48a463d5fa5622734bc38b
while processing commit 642d437e3080f869503f663b2ea0013cb85ebe8a.
error: Fetch failed.
```

Does anyone know what's wrong and how I can fix?   As mentioned, i don't encounter this error on any other linux computers and servers.

Additional notes: I typed in the same username and password on 8 different computers/passwords. The only time it fails is on my www-data@john-laptop computer. I suspect this might have something to do with my upgrade from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. Maybe i'll try re-installing git on that computer.  Does anyone know of related issues?  git works differently on different OS?

Comment: Why the downvote and close?  Isn't this the place to be asking about git server and/or linux based servers?

Comment: It says your username and password are wrong. So check those.

Comment: I did not downvote, or VTC; but I strongly suspect that they're on account of [SF] being for Professional System Administrators *only*, who should know that 401 means "user error", not a problem with the software.

Answer (score 3):

`The requested URL returned error: 401` == Unauthorized

Check your username and password or other form of authorization.

Comment: I typed in the same username and password one 8 different computers/passwords.  The only time it fails is on my john@laptop computer.  I suspect this might have something to do with my upgrade from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04.  Maybe i'll try re-installing git on that computer.  Do you know anything that might be related?

Comment: @John Do you have access to logs? That way you can verify if the username/pw you see matches what the server sees. At least with that you can see if its a server problem or client problem